# multiple ref_cursor returned as out parameter from oracle stored procedure using JPA

Tags: spring, oracle, stored-procedures, spring-data-jpa

how can i retrieve multiple ref_cursor returned as out parameter from oracle stored procedure using spring JPA version 2.1